# Can VIM do this Sublime trick?

Tags: vim

I want to edit this text:

```
Aenean vel sem bibendum, eleifend odio a, dictum nibh.
The third word in the above line is 
Morbi eget est vitae quam ultricies porta vitae quis nunc.
The third word in the above line is 
Praesent accumsan ex a laoreet cursus.
The third word in the above line is 
Quisque efficitur lectus at dolor mollis, sit amet tristique libero lobortis.
The third word in the above line is
```

to this text:

```
Aenean vel sem bibendum, eleifend odio a, dictum nibh.
The third word in the above line is sem
Morbi eget est vitae quam ultricies porta vitae quis nunc.
The third word in the above line is est
Praesent accumsan ex a laoreet cursus.
The third word in the above line is ex
Quisque efficitur lectus at dolor mollis, sit amet tristique libero lobortis.
The third word in the above line is lectus
```

To do this with Sublime

```
Select repeated part
ALT+F3
UpArrow
HOME
3 x CTRL+RightArrow
CTRL+Shift+LeftArrow
CTRL+C
DownArrow
END
CTRL+V
```

this trick is very useful in many cases.
can VIM do it?

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors

Comment: Expert VIM users says that vim-multiple-cursors is a bad idea and it have a lot of problems while VIM native features can do everything vim-multiple-cursors can do

Comment: True, I was just offering it as a suggestion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should work easily with a macro. If you have your cursor on the first character of the first line then:

`qq`: start recording macro named `q`

`2w`: advance two words

`yw`: yank (copy) word

`j$`: jump to next line and go to end of line

`p`: paste what you've yanked

`+`: go to start of next line

`q`: stop recording macro.

`3@q`: execute macro named `q` 3 times

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a macro solution, you could also use a substitute command

```
:%s/\vis $\zs/\=split(getline(line('.')-1), ' ')[2]
```

**breakdown**

```
:%s/                                      start a substitute command
\vis $\zs/                                select lines ending with "is "
                                          use \zs to start replacing after the match
\=split(getline(line('.')-1), ' ')[2]     split previous line on spaces and use the 3th item from the list
```

Note that to use this as a general template following has to hold

- You need a search criteria to only match the lines you like to change. For your example, this is `is $`
- You need to be able to split the previous line on something meaningfull returning the item you need in the same array position for each substituion. For you example this is by splitting on space and returning the 3th item.

Answer (score 1):

Another vim solution:

```
:g/^/if line('.') % 2 | normal! wwyiwj$p | endif


g .................. globally
/^/ ................ on every start of line
if
line('.') % 2 ...... Mod of the integer division of line number by 2
normal! ............ normal mode
ww ................. jump to the third word
yiw ................ yank inner word (word under cursor)
j .................. go to the line below
$ .................. jump to othe end of the line
p .................. paste
```